# grep -B emulation with ring buffer / awk

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, grep

I need to extract a line above my search string (say, 19 lines above). Normally, I would just go with

```
grep -B 19 $search_string $file | ...further processing
```

However the script should also work with on Solaris, where grep doesn't provide the **-B** option. Often, I can get away with `awk '/begin/,/end/'` to print a bunch of lines, if I know the preceding lines. In this particular situation, this is not possible. I tried the following:

1) Ring buffer solution.

```
#!/bin/bash
g_a_buffer=( 0 )
g_i_buffer_index=1
while read line
        do
        g_a_buffer[$((g_i_buffer_index % 20))]=$line
        echo $line|grep $search_string > /dev/null
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo ${g_a_buffer[$(( (g_i_buffer_index + 2) % 20))]}
        let "g_i_buffer_index += 1"
        done < $file_name
```

This is **extremely slow**. For ~40k lines it takes 1m37s (against 0.005s for grep)

2) Awk solution. I have to say outright that I am an extrem beginner in awk, rarely going beyond awk '{print $1}'. **The below line doesn't work**, but gives you an idea of what I am trying to achieve:

```
awk '/mySearchString/ {print NR-19}' filename.txt
```

0.118s for execution, the speed is good! But all I get is a line number - 19. What I need is a printout of the line located at (line - 19). After some googling I still couldn't find an answer. I admit this must be an extremely basic problem, but I seem to have hit a wall here.

All I found so far is how to print a previous line with awk (which is a sort of 1 line buffer), or massive implementations with ring buffer but in awk. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: `grep` is usually a program distinct from bash, and many people on Solaris just install the GNU tools (like grep) in an alternate path (/opt/gnu) to supplement their antique Sun variants. Might be more efficient in your case.

Comment: Thiton, unfortunately this is not possible, and I have to do with what's available.

Comment: Derobert: this is where semantics come into play — perl is sure available on the Solaris server in question, but I have exactly zero experience with perl. So yes, I may but I can't :) I'll run with your solution with `grep -n` below, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution which requires two passes through the file so is not optimal, but may well perform reasonably in practice. (Tested on GNU awk, but no obvious reason why it would not work on Solaris).

```
awk "$(awk '/mySearchString/ { print "NR==" NR-19 }' myInputFile.txt)" myInputFile.txt
```

As this requires two passes, if you are piping the input from elsewhere you will need to store it in a temporary file somewhere.

Alternatively if you know that your search string will appear at most once in the file (or at least you only care about the first occurrence), you could combine awk with head and tail to extract the line:

```
awk 'NR==1,/mySearchString/' | tail -n 19 | head -n 1
```

I don't have a suitable text file handy to benchmark this, but I would expect it to be a fair amount better than your ring buffer solution.

Comment: Theo, there are more occurrences than 1 (3 to 6, let's say)

Comment: Theo, `awk "$(awk '/mySearchString/ { print "NR==" NR-19 }' myInputFile.txt)" myInputFile.txt` actually works quite nicely!! I'll go with this one, I think it's more elegant than `grep -n / head / tail`solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use `grep -n` (which should be there, since `-n` is specified by POSIX) to get the line number of each match.

```
file="foo"
for line in $(grep -n "pattern" "$file" | cut -d: -f1); do
  end=`expr $line + 1`
  head -n $end "$file" | tail -n 3
done
```

That's `-B 1`, but it sounds like you just want *n*-19, so you could do:

```
  target=`expr $line - 19`
  head -n $target "$file" | tail -n 1
```

Won't be as fast as grep, and I didn't handle possible overlaps in the `-B 1` case (will output lines twice), but should work. Optimization could be done with `grep -b` (for byte offset) if you have that.

Comment: Derobert, yes `grep -n` works on Solaris so I can now do the `head -N|tail -1` trick. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat mySearcher.sh
#!/bin/ksh

awk '{ array[i++]=$0 }
     END {
       maxI=++i
      for (j=0;j<maxI; j++) {
        if (array[j] ~ /'"${1}"'/) {  #searchTarget
           print array[j-19]
        }
      }
     }
   ' "$2"
```

make it executable

```
$ chmod 755 mySearch.sh
```

called as

```
$ mySearcher.sh "search target" file
```

Should be a good start to solving your problem

You're reading all your data into an awk array (monster files may be a problem), 
then in the END block, loop thru the array, matching each record against your search target'

This won't deal well with the case where your searchTarget is before line 19. You can also amend this script to use the same technique as $1 for the search target  to make the 'look-back' number a parameter.

I Hope this helps.

Comment: Shellter, thank you very much. I suspect a small ring buffer (20 lines) would be more efficient if implemented in awk (bash is definitely not a way to go when dealing with arrays, as I learned), esp. seeing how I have to deal with multiple files 2-3MB each. I wouldn't dare load the whole file into memory, since this is a server with loads of users.. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n ':a;s/\n/&/19;tc;:b;$q;N;ba;:c;/\nPATTERN$/{h;x;s/\n.*//p;x};s/^[^\n]*\n//;ta'
```

Another cheap-and-nasty (does not handle overlaps) is:

```
tac | sed -n '/PATTERN/,+19{h;d};x;/^$/!{p;s/.*//};x' | tac
```

Both probably require GNU sed

Comment: Potong, thanks for the reply! I went with the awk way — at least I can understand what's going on there :) As a minor gripe, I don't have tac on mac..

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it!
The "right" AWK answer is:

```
awk '$NF ~ "regex" {print $(NF-1)}' input_file
```